# Nullable reference types: "Try" method pattern, getting warning for null when returning false

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have the following method which is using the "Try" pattern.

```
public bool TryGetValue(string subnet, [NotNullWhen(true)] out TValue value)
{
    if (!TryFindNode(subnet, out var node))
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    if (TValueIsDefault(node.Value) == false)
    {
        value = node.Value;
        return true;
    }
    value = default;
    return false;
}
```

On the line `value = default` - I am getting a compiler warning CS8601: "Possible null reference assignment".  The next line returns `false`, and `value` has the `[NotNullWhen(true)]` attribute.

Am I missing something, or is the compiler not carrying the state of `value` for some reason?

Full sample on [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) and a [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/binarycow/544ed3d3ca74706219929c9c737ca86d)

Comment: Try to use `value = default!;`

Comment: I know I can use the null forgiving operator to bypass the warning - but the attribute should indicate to the compiler the null status of that variable... I am looking to confirm/deny whether or not this is a supported use of the attributes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(The following answer is applicable as of Visual Studio 16.6/.NET Core 3.1)

You should use `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]` instead of `[NotNullWhen(true)]` in this scenario.

```cs
public bool TryGetValue(string subnet, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TValue value)
{
    if (!TryFindNode(subnet, out var node))
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    if (TValueIsDefault(node.Value) == false)
    {
        value = node.Value;
        return true;
    }
    value = default;
    return false;
}
```

---

Explanation:

The key point to understand is that applying a `[NotNullWhen(true)]` attribute does not imply `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]`.

In your sample, it is permitted to supply a non-nullable reference type such as `string` as a type argument for `TValue`. This would produce the following method:

```cs
public bool TryGetValue(string subnet, [NotNullWhen(true)] out string value)
{
    if (!TryFindNode(subnet, out var node))
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    if (TValueIsDefault(node.Value) == false)
    {
        value = node.Value;
        return true;
    }
    value = default; // Wait, default(string) is null! We can't do this!
    return false;
}
```

What you probably want to do is instead of telling your caller the method will return "not null when true", tell them it "may return null when false". Then the **type argument** to your containing type `TreeNode<TValue>` will inform whether the caller should expect a non-null `value` when this method returns true. Thus the instantiation looks like:

```cs
public bool TryGetValue(string subnet, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string value)
{
    if (!TryFindNode(subnet, out var node))
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    if (TValueIsDefault(node.Value) == false)
    {
        value = node.Value;
        return true;
    }
    value = default; // ok
    return false;
}
```

Since the target of the assignment has `MaybeNullWhen`, the compiler permits you to assign null to it. We simply check in your return statement that the null-state of the variable is compatible with the return value. For example, if we changed `return false` to `return true` above, you would get a nullability warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look how the similar methods, like [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Dictionary.cs,2e5bc6d8c0f21e67,references), are implemented in .NET Core. In your case you should use [null-forgiving operator `!`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) to suppress the warning (since `TValue` declared as non-nullable type)

```cs
value = default!;
return false;
```

Comment: Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue isn't a good example, because Dictionary supports null values for TValue.

I am using the [NotNullWhen(true)] attribute which should tell the compiler it is not null, and not present a warning.  I know that I can using the null forgiving operator to bypass it - but, it *shouldn't* need that?

Comment: @MikeChristiansen `TValue` is declared as non-nullable type and doesn't constrained to `class` or `struct`. You should use `!` operator to suppress a warning because `[NotNullWhen(true)]` works only for positive `if` branch. Or you cna declare type as `TValue?` and constrain it to `class` or `struct` (which doesn't seem to be a good option)

Comment: "...[NotNullWhen(true)] works only for positive if branch..."

@PavelAnikhouski Where did you find this information?